# regular expression to shift a string

Tags: python, regex

so i have this String

```
if(LTBInitIsOver):
    ALL_SetModuleTraceLevelByName( "GfeLib", 2)
    ALL_SetModuleTraceLevelByName( "ComStack", 2)
    ALL_SetModuleTraceLevelByName( "ComStackIf", 2)
    ALL_SetModuleTraceLevelByName( "CnxMgr", 2)
    ALL_SetModuleTraceLevelByName( "OLC", 2)
    ALL_SetModuleTraceLevelByName( "TBNub", 1)
```

I want to make this String looks exactly like python's syntax, in other words i want to shift all lines under the 'if condition' to the right, 'tab'.

I tried `re.sub` with `"(^if.*:)"` but I could not find the right regular expression.

Comment: When you "tried re.sub", what was the regex you tried?

Comment: i tried a lot, for exp: "(^if.*:)\n"

Answer (score 0):

You could actually just replace `\n` with `\n\t` in the string, but if you really need to use a regular expression to replace only within a `if block`, the solution is the following:

```
import re

string = """if(LTBInitIsOver):
ALL_SetModuleTraceLevelByName("GfeLib", 2)
ALL_SetModuleTraceLevelByName("ComStack", 2)
ALL_SetModuleTraceLevelByName("ComStackIf", 2)
ALL_SetModuleTraceLevelByName("CnxMgr", 2)
ALL_SetModuleTraceLevelByName("OLC", 2)
ALL_SetModuleTraceLevelByName("TBNub", 1)"""

re_pattern = re.compile('(if.+)\n?', re.S)

ifblock = re.findall(re_pattern, string)[0].replace('\n', '\n\t')

print(ifblock)
```

Prints

```
if(LTBInitIsOver):
    ALL_SetModuleTraceLevelByName("GfeLib", 2)
    ALL_SetModuleTraceLevelByName("ComStack", 2)
    ALL_SetModuleTraceLevelByName("ComStackIf", 2)
    ALL_SetModuleTraceLevelByName("CnxMgr", 2)
    ALL_SetModuleTraceLevelByName("OLC", 2)
    ALL_SetModuleTraceLevelByName("TBNub", 1)
```